# Git repository setup with binaries

Tags: git

My company is considering implementing Git but I have a question about what the best way would be to set it up. We have 3 sites and are planning on using Gerrit2 to create mirrors. Our repository is about 2GB and we would like to start adding binaries to it. I'm concerned about the space usage though. I don't mind if all versions of the binaries are stored in a handful of locations but I want to make sure that they don't bog down clone operations.

I understand that Git uses hard links but I think that will only work if we place a copy of the repository on every mount. Are there better options and if so what are the tradeoffs? Options that I'm looking at are "--shared" and "--reference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just use native git, use a separate repo to house the binaries via git submodules. This has worked for me on IVR systems which had a ton of gigantic .wav files. If you need further clarification, feel free to contact me.

Here's a good write up on them:

http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html

hope this helps

Comment: Submodules look interesting but how do they interact with partial checkouts? Can I specify that I want to check out only a portion of the submodule or do I have to check out the entire thing?

Comment: that can be handled with special branches within the submodule repo that would have the files you need.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative to [`git media`](https://github.com/schacon/git-media) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956675/git-repository-setup-with-binaries/5956703#5956703) by [Marcelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9990/marcelo-cantos) is **[git annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)**:

See [what git-annex is not](http://git-annex.branchable.com/not/):

> git-annex is not git-media, although they both approach the same problem from a similar direction. I only learned of git-media after writing git-annex, but I probably would have still written git-annex instead of using it.
>
> Currently, git-media has the advantage of using git smudge filters rather than git-annex's pile of symlinks, and it may be a tighter fit for certain situations.
> It lacks git-annex's support for widely distributed storage, using only a single backend data store.
> It also does not support partial checkouts of file contents, like git-annex does.

---

Note: [abdelsaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007877/abdelsaid) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956675/git-repository-setup-with-binaries/5956726?noredirect=1#comment35714408_5956726):

You can use git-annex with **[bup](https://github.com/bup/bup)** (bup allows you to have versions), see  [`git-annex/ special remotes/ bup`](http://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/bup/) (and [Using bup](http://git-annex.branchable.com/walkthrough/using_bup/))

I have presented bup in more details in "[git with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494211/6309)"

Comment: Doesn't seem to allow you to keep multiple revisions of binaries, only store those that you have separately.

Comment: I know this is old comment but if somebody is coming here, you can use git-annex with bup (bup allows you to have versions), see https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/bup/

Comment: @abdelsaid good update. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and i have added a link to another answer of mine where I talked about bup.

Answer (score 3):

Use [git-media](https://github.com/schacon/git-media) for large binaries. It stores references to binaries as SHA1 sums and hosts the binaries themselves in a place (and protocol) of your choosing. When you do a clone, it only fetches the binaries necessary to checkout the working copy.

Comment: That could complicate syncing to all sites as Gerrit2 wouldn't pick them up. Partial checkout support also seems to be missing, per comments below. Interesting option though.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility is [git-fat](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat) (or Cyan's [fork](https://github.com/cyaninc/git-fat) of git-fat with some enhancements); it is even lighter weight (depends only on Python and rsync) than [git-media](https://github.com/schacon/git-media) (Ruby), and definitely lighter than [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) (Haskell).  The cost of that is less configurability, but this may be the best solution in some cases.