# Private pod resources are not copied while importing it to another project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, git, cocoapods

I am using private pod. In its .podspec file I mentioned the image resources path.

```
s.resources = 'Pod/Assets/*/*/*.{png}'
```

But while installing it to another project its images are not added to that project?
In-fact while pushing the private pod to github I am not seeing any image resources to push in my sourcetree. Looks like git is avoiding them. But if i am putting them directly in

```
Pod/Assets
```

Then I am able to push images on github also. So does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably have some ignore rules set for ignoring those files in filepath `'Pod/Assets/*/*/*.{png}'`

Check your `$PROJECT_DIR/.gitignore` and `$PROJECT_DIR/.git/info/exclude` files and remove those ignore rules, and it should start working fine.

PS: Ideally, the images should not be a part of git repo, and so I would suggest retaining your current settings if possible.

Comment: IF the images should not be a part of git repo Then how to share across teams and within different projects that install them ?

Comment: @kidsid49 You can save them, but it is usually not recommended for multiple reasons, eg. 1) git is not efficient for tracking binary/image files 2) git [might crash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10405107/1860929) on a rebase between images 3) every image is backed up in the `.git` folder, which makes cloning and deployment suboptimal and so on. You can read more [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/80962/91731)